# Need to make Grid width of page I'm going to print it on

Tags: xaml, silverlight-5.0

I'm making simple report, just hard-coding it pretty much. I have one Grid which contains textboxes and such.

I want to make this Grid size of printable area of standard Letter (-1 inch for non-printable). What size it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good article here about printing in Silverlight:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148152.aspx

Where he states:

PrintPageEventArgs has two handy get-only properties that also report sizes in units of 1/96th inch: PrintableArea of type Size provides the dimensions of the area of the printable area of the page, and PageMargins of type Thickness is the width of the left, top, right and bottom of the unprintable edges. Add these two together (in the right way) and you get the full size of the paper.

My printer—when loaded with standard 8.5 x 11 inch paper and set for portrait mode—reports a PrintableArea of 791 x 993. The four values of the PageMargins property are 12 (left), 6 (top), 12 (right) and 56 (bottom). If you sum the horizontal values of 791, 12 and 12, you’ll get 815. The vertical values are 994, 6 and 56, which sum to 1,055. I’m not sure why there’s a one-unit difference between these values and the values of 816 and 1,056 obtained by multiplying the page size in inches by 96.